# How to declare an array string or initialize it in vb?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I try this but return error

```
 Public Function Coba() As String()
 Return {"satu", "dua", "tiga"} End Function
```

But this is ok :

```
Public Function Test() As String()
 Return New String() {"anjing", "badak", "kucing"} End Function
```

Why the first one is error ? and can i create an array without initializing it first , maybe some shortcut way?

Comment: what error do you get and where for the first?

Comment: This works fine. Both the codes work fine, in fact. See it working [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wuFFg6).

Comment: i am using VS 2008 and got error..

Comment: `got error`  **what error**?  *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error...*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try this maybe help you

```
'array integer'
Dim i as Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4}
'array object '
Dim o() = {1, 2, 3}
'array string '
Dim array1() as String() = {"1", "2", "3" }
```

try to read this

[Arrays in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; leave alone the fact that the question if off-topic because the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: this work dudes.. thank you maybe it is because i use VS 2008, anyway but this code worked, dunno why..

Comment: this is just what the OP has in the second block

Comment: i just try to help her/him with my basic array answer and some links for her/him, sorry if i am wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You really should create objects of the expected type then pass these objects (an array in this case back to the caller).

Personally this is first example is the way to go rather than the second. Both are simple and may not make a good deal of sense but generally speaking many times we are getting array data from a source e.g. get files in a folder, get data from reading from a database etc and is not so visible by using a variable we can debug easily and also have a public symbol rather than a anonymous symbol thinking clean up of memory.

Sample 1

```
Public Function NameArray() As String()
    Dim values As String() = New String() {"satu", "dua", "tiga"}
    Return values
End Function
```

Sample 2

```
Public Function NameArray() As String()
    Return New String() {"satu", "dua", "tiga"}
End Function
```

Both are valid in VS2013 (I know you are using VS2008). The next example the array has been created already so we simply return it.

```
Public Function AbbreviatedMonthNames() As String()
    Return System.Globalization _
        .CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat _
        .AbbreviatedMonthNames
End Function
```

Bottom line, when in doubt have Option Strict On and go the long route when coding rather than taking short cuts because many times when coding short cuts lead to issues.